# Observer behavior in Minecraft version 1.11

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm playing Minecraft: Java Edition, 1.11 on PC. The reason I'm playing this version is because of the lack of OptiFine releases for the current version. 
My question is concerning the behavior of Observers in this version.

I built a pumpkin farm as shown in the screenshot below. The farm works, but the Observer facing the pumpkin is only sending redstone pulses two times:
First is when the pumpkin grows and the second is when the piston retracts.

My question is, why the Observer is not sending a pulse when the piston extends? Doesn't that count as a block update?

If that's right, then the observer should send  a total of three redstone pulses, which would obviously break this farm. But that's not the case.

[image: Automated pumpkin farm]

Comment: I think it would help to see the farm from a few more angles.  From this angle, I can't clearly see how the farm even works to begin with.

Comment: @MBraedley, thanks for the comment. But I can't post screenshots as I'm in work. However I can detail its working. Whenever a pumpkin grows, the Observer below activates the sticky piston above which in turn pulls the Observer in front of it. This Observer activates the piston below and it breaks the pumpkin. When the piston retracts the Observer causes the sticky piston to push the Observer above, back to its original position.

Comment: On another note im pretty sure there is optifine for the current version. It's listed on their download page https://optifine.net/downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing and it seems like observers have a 1-tick cooldown time.

The observer detects when the piston extends and breaks the melon block, one tick later the piston retracts, which is not detected by the observer, because it is still within it's cooldown time.

Another tick later there is an air block in that spot, which doesn't have a block update.

I rebuilt your farm like this in 1.11.2 and it should be accurate:

[image: recreation of the setup from the question]

*Note: This is from personal testing and not from any official source, it appears to be correct, but it may be wrong.*

Comment: The lower piston seems to be powered by the upper observer by utilising quasi-connectivity. The piston is supposed to be powered by the observer, BUT it should require a block update to notice that it's beeing powered. Can anyone eplain how the piston knows that it's being powered by quasi-connectivity in this case? I tested this in 1.14.3 and it works there, too.

Comment: so does this imply that Observers had a 1 redstone tick cooldown?

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo That's a much better way to word it. I didn't test 2 or more tick pulses, so it may be a longer cooldown.

Comment: It is a 1 tick cooldown.

Comment: Now that I think of it, you can have a 1-tick clock by having 2 observers face each other, so I kind of already knew that, but I didn't think about it earlier

Comment: @bearb001, I'm kind of puzzled, if Observer had a cooldown, then how is it detecting the extension of the piston below, if it just detected the pumpkin below it one tick before?

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo I would have to do a bit more research to get an exact value, but there are at least 2 ticks between the melon growing and the piston that breaks it extending. a cooldown time of 1 tick does not interfere with this.

Comment: @bearb001, are you taking into account that Observers didn't have the one tick delay as it has in the current version?

Comment: @SlayerDiAngelo In an extreme case (because I'm currently not sure how quickly everything moves), the observer detects the melon and turns on. As long as it is on, the upper piston would be extended and it wouldn't retract until the observer turns off again. When the observer turns off, the piston retracts, this alone should take at least one more tick. Also: the lower piston does not extend at the same time as the upper piston retracts (Or at least I think so, it's not much time in between so there is a possibility that my judgement, or my memory from when I tested it is off)

Comment: I did some testing now, I'm not completely sure how accurate it is, but it seems like there are 9 ticks between the melon growing and the melon being broken by the second piston in both versions. I'm not sure how accurate the method was, but the error should be less than 2 ticks.

Comment: I realized that I was measuring game ticks, this would mean that it's 2, or 3 redstone ticks between the melon growing and the melon being broken.

Comment: @bearb001, thanks for your effort. Is there any way to make this farm less resource intensive? Right now it uses a ton of Observers and pistons to automate just three pumpkin patches!

Comment: I saw one design somewhere that uses a flying machine to break and collect the melons, it would be fairly expensive, but extending it would basically cost nothing except for dirt, hoes, and water. You can also make a time based solution, which would require one piston and a little redstone dust per block where melons grow. You can then use one clock for many melon spots.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96314/discussion-between-slayerdiangelo-and-bearb001).